# Does PayPal have APIs for various restricted operations?

Tags: paypal

Like the following:

1. Withdraw money from PayPal
2. Send money or payments
3. Pay using PayPal
4. Receive money or payments
5. Refund money to customers

Answer (score 0):

Strange question, but as best I know:

- Withdraw to a bank? No
- There is the [Payouts API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts)
- PayPal Checkout?
- PayPal Checkout? With or without a `payee` set?
- Who received the payment that is going to be refunded? Yes there is an operation that depends on the API used to receive the payment, but it is a matter of having permissions to execute it. You can refund payments to your own account of course.

Comment: Maybe I have some problems with the description, please forgive my bad English. I want to get my paypal account status via api, like account limit (https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/why-is-my-paypal-account-limited-faq1758)

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with any of the above, but no there is no get whether your account is limited. API operations will just return an error to the affect of "Account is restricted" if the account being operated on is limited.

Comment: so ,there is not api get this info ?(https://postimg.cc/H8cW8jdk)

Comment: Correct. You should resolve limitations as soon as possible within www.paypal.com , usually by responding with required information about the business. An API is rather beside the point and serves no purpose

Comment: I have many paypal account ,  for get limits info , i must login in, and check it is limited. if exist api to get account is limited or not, I  will reduce a lot of work

Comment: Consider consolidating your business into fewer PayPal accounts. You can set the 'BRANDNAME' api parameter or similar so a different store name appears during checkout.